# executing .exe with argument and multiple commands from C#

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to "convert" a bash script I wrote to C#.
This script starts a program in a shell and then executes a few commands in this shell and looks similar to this:

```
cd /$MYPATH
./executible -s << EOF
start_source_probe -hardware_name "USB" -device_name "@1: EP3C(10|5)"
write_source_data -instance_index 0 -value "11111"
write_source_data -instance_index 0 -value "10111"
write_source_data -instance_index 0 -value "00111"
exit
EOF
```

Now I would like to do the same using Visual Studio C#.
At the moment my attempt looks like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "pathToExe\\";
startInfo.FileName= "executible.exe";
startInfo.Arguments= "-s";
//startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
//startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
proc.Start();
//StreamWriter myStreamWriter = proc.StandardInput;
//Console.WriteLine("start_source_probe - hardware_name \"USB\" -device_name \"@1: EP3C(10|5)\"");
//Console.WriteLine("write_source_data -instance_index 0 -value \"11111\"");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

With the comments activated (so with the "//" in code) I manage to open the shell (-s stands for shell) but I wonder how I am able to execute commands in this shell additionally.
I managed to execute multiple commands with something like this (as long as I am not starting the shell because destination output differs I guess)

```
const string strCmdText = "/C command1&command2";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to add the argument "-s" and execute commands in the started process.

Comment: I find that multiple commands with cmd.exe is awkward at best. Better off if you write out your commands into a .cmd file and execute that. You'll have "normal" batch syntax in your .cmd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i did understood your question, but you can create a batch file outside your c# code and call It from your c# code like the following :

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ProcStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
ProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ProcStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
ProcStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process MyProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcStartInfo.Arguments = "/c start /wait batch.bat ";
MyProcess.StartInfo = ProcStartInfo;
MyProcess.Start();
MyProcess.WaitForExit();
```

I added the `/wait` so your c# code is going to wait for your batch to finish, to pursuit the c# code execution

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a here document like the "<< EOF ......" in my bash script in a batch script or make something with the same result?

Comment: I did not understood your question, what do you mean by "add a here document like the" and "in my bash script in a batch script or make"

Comment: doesnt matter anymore. I figured out how to do it. "type sometext.txt | myexe.exe -s" helped. Thx for your answer!